# Track progress when uploading file to Rackspace Cloud Files in C#

Tags: c#, .net, rackspace-cloud, cloudfiles

I am using https://github.com/rackspace/csharp-cloudfiles to bulid a command-line tool to upload files to Rackspace Cloud Files.

The thing is that I don't know how to track upload progress (there doesn't seem to be any kind of event or something).

Here's the code:

```
// Create credentials, client and connection
var creds = new UserCredentials(username, apiKey);
CF_Client client = new CF_Client();
Connection conn = new CF_Connection(creds, client);
conn.Authenticate();

// Get container and upload file
var container = new CF_Container(conn, client, containerName);
var obj = new CF_Object(conn, container, client, remoteFileName);
obj.WriteFromFile(localFilePath);
```

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't look like there's one built-in, no, but you could probably add your own.

An alternative would be to measure the input; if you look at [the source](https://github.com/rackspace/csharp-cloudfiles/blob/master/src/Rackspace.Cloudfiles/CF_Object.cs) you'll see that WriteFromFile is effectively just

```
Dictionary<string,string> headers = new Dictionary<string,string>();
using(Stream stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(localFilePath))
{
    obj.Write(stream, headers);
}
```

so you could wrap the stream you pass to Write in another stream class that measures total-bytes-read progress (there's a few around if you search, or it'd be easy enough to write yourself). If you did want to add progress notifications back from their code you'd need to add it to the wrapped [OpenStack Client object](http://swift.openstack.org/misc.html#swift.common.client.put_object) but that shouldn't be too hard either.